# Run script on all files in dir sharing a common id

Tags: bash, shell

I have some files in a dir:

```
A573R25.file_1.txt
A573R25.file_2.txt
A573R25.file_3.txt
A573R27.file_1.txt
A573R27.file_2.txt
A573R29.file_1.txt
A573R29.file_2.txt
A573R29.file_3.txt
A573R31.file_1.txt
A573R31.file_2.txt
A573R31.file_3.txt
A573R33.file_1.txt
A573R33.file_2.txt
A573R33.file_3.txt
```

I want to run a script on all files sharing a common id (but with varying text separating the id (e.g. `A573R25`) and `.txt`). For example:

`perl my_script.pl A573R25*.txt`

However, I want to do this for all files in the dir in a bash script.

Here's what I've tried:

```
samples+=$(ls -1 *.txt | cut -d '.' -f 1)

for ((i=0;i<${#samples[@]};++i))
do
  ls -1 ${samples[i]}*.txt
```

done

But in each case I get (e.g.): 
`ls: A573R25: No such file or directory`

My expected output for the first id is:

```
A573R25.file_1.txt
A573R25.file_2.txt
A573R25.file_3.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `sort -u` in your sample collection, and it needs to be an array set:

```
samples+=( $( ls -1 *.txt | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sort -u ) )
```

Here is full code and results:

```
$ unset samples
$ samples+=( $(ls -1 *.txt | cut -d '.' -f 1 | sort -u ) )
$ for ((i=0;i<${#samples[@]};++i)); do ls -1 ${samples[i]}*.txt; done
A573R25.file_1.txt
A573R25.file_2.txt
A573R25.file_3.txt
A573R27.file_1.txt
A573R27.file_2.txt
A573R29.file_1.txt
A573R29.file_2.txt
A573R29.file_3.txt
A573R31.file_1.txt
A573R31.file_2.txt
A573R31.file_3.txt
A573R33.file_1.txt
A573R33.file_2.txt
A573R33.file_3.txt
```